# Python YouTube API Skip Entering Authentication Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to automate the code that changes thumbnails with the YouTube api.
I have to enter the authentication key every time I do it, so is there a way to omit this part?

[terminal when running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHRqY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `python-youtube`:

The documentation clearly listed how to initialize it with access token or api-key:

```py
>>> from pyyoutube import Api
>>> api = Api(api_key="your api key")
```

Or with access token:

```py
>>> from pyyoutube import Api
>>> api = Api(access_token='your api key')
```

More can be found [here](https://github.com/sns-sdks/python-youtube)

Comment: This may be a little rude request, could you please make a code for me?

Comment: This might help you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/8277795. We don't offer software writing service but helps who are stucked while solving their issue. Writing your code would mean you haven't done any research (you need to learn to code) or are looking for service (for which freelance website exists). Anyway, we'll always help you.